# Sending messages between two separate objects

Tags: objective-c, oop, messaging

Say for example I have two objects A and B and that object B has a method called 'update'.

Within object A I have a line which sends the message `[objectB update]`.
However I get the message:

> error 'objectB' undeclared (first use in this function).

The thing is that objectB was declared in my Appdelegate along with objectA.
Seems a bit silly that objectA cannot message objectB directly.
I realise this may be some kind of scope issue but my question is really do I try to make objectA global? or do I setup a system of passing pointers back and forth making things quite messy?

Comment: Let's say that you, being a good object oriented programmer, use the ObjectA class in another program. Can it assume that objectB will exist?

Answer (score 2):

Take this:

```
[self.objectB update];
```

And your AppDelegate.m, you have write this:

```
@synthesize objectB;
```

I believe that it's object is private or not a getter method.

Answer (score 1):

Since *objectB* is a member of *app delegate*, access it like this.

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate;
appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.objectB update];
```